# Objects are not as stable as ARKit

Tags: google-project-tango, arkit

I have used [this](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-howto-placing-objects) tutorial in order to create working example project. But when I move around with device, object is also moving slightly with me (even Lowe's Vision app) but ARKit keeping object a lot more stable than Tango. Is there any guide to fix this issue or Tango is not ready for using in real world applications (other than cases where slightly unstable objects are ok to tolerate, like in games)?

Answer (score 0):

What "Tango" device, if it is the Dev Kit, then that 3 year old Tegra chip and older hardware is probably the bottle-neck as the Phab 2 Pro can compute and track **way** better then the old Dev Kit as I have compared them next to each other.

I have also compared my Phab 2 Pro with a Tango C API demo to the standard ARKit demo and the Tango has way better tracking since it has the depth camera as ARKit is just good software over a normal RGB camera. But this depth camera loses a lot of its advantage if you are clogging it with the abstraction layer set on Unity.

Also to my knowledge I am not sure how you can really quantify "more stable" as it might be the applications fault, not the hardware

Comment: Lenovo Phab 2 Pro

Comment: "more stable" - object is staying at a place where you put it initially and do not move with you when you are moving, thats the case with my demo. Whenever I move slightly, object is also moving with me in Tango

Comment: There is a `config_enable_drift_correction` flag that can be optionally set in the C API 
https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/reference/group/config-params

Not sure how Unity works with Tango, but this might not be enabled and that would for sure cause that miss-tracking of the object